# Can't load Javascript library: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: javascript, html

I have an Apache web server where I must display some graphs and I must be able to do it offline. I have a couple of js libraries I must use in order to render the graphs and when I load my index.php page, it gives me `GET http:d3.js/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`, but the file is in the right folder and I've copied and pasted the code in index.php in a test file and when I open it, it works just fine.

The html for the graphs is being generated using the MPLD3 function of fig_to_html, this function generates an html string, that I append to my index.php, the path to the js libraries is also specified in that function:

```
mpld3.fig_to_html(fig, mpld3_url='file:///home/pi/webpage/mpld3.js, d3_url='file:///home/pi/webpage/d3.js')
```

Comment: You need to show us some code. With your description is impossible to visualize where the problem may be. At least, you need to show us the code where you load the js libraries, as it seems you're trying to load them over the network rather than locally

Comment: Using `file` protocol seems wrong, if there's a server, you should be using a url for that server's path (like `http://localhost/pi/webpage/d3.js`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not seem a valid file url:

```
http:d3.js/
```

Try "d3.js" or "/[path-on-site]/d3.js".